# Firefox does not run and opens up blank

Tags: selenium

I am using a script created weeks ago in Firefox.  When I loaded it up, Firefox opens but blanks out and doesn't run.

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 
            4444, 
            "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", 
            "http://www.test.com/");
selenium.Start();
```

Do Firefox profiles get in the way?  It opens up a new instance of Firefox everytime but doesn't go to the test site.

Answer (score 1):

By writing  `"http://www.test.com/"` for your selenium instance you just provide *base url* for your tests. To navigate to your test site you should use `selenium.open("/")` command. To navigate to `"http://www.test.com/test.html"` you should use `selenium.open("/test.html")` and so on.